# upload CosmosDB indexing policy with Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible Via Powershell to upload a Json Document to Replace the Current Indexing Policy on a CosmosDB Database, if so How? we would like to be able to deploy a completed File rather than edit the file via the portal, we can then implement versioning, then no one is hand editing files, or cutting and pasting.

Comment: The answer to "is it possible" questions is almost always "yes". What have you tried so far? What didn't work the way you expected? What does your code look like?

Comment: The API has a replace collection method which updates the collection's properties such as the IndexingPolicy so yeah it is possible, but I agree with what Ansgar said.

Comment: I have tried a Package Called COSMOSDB off of git, it has such control but look like it is only when creating a Collection, Not Modifying an existing policy. I have explored the Azure CLI tools to no avail, there is no existing code to match as it is a new project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Azure CLI (which can run through powershell) in order to run the 
`az cosmosdb collection update` command which can be found here [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cosmosdb/collection?view=azure-cli-latest#az-cosmosdb-collection-update).

You will need to use the `--indexing-policy` optional parameter to achieve this.

You can enter it as a string or as a file, e.g., --indexing-policy @policy-file.json)

For the record if you use the `--url-connection` and `--key` arguments you won't need to az login.

Comment: What exactly is this thing @policy-file.json is it a string, is it a parameter?